# 60+% of the requests give curl error URL error 7: Failed to connect

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5, homestead, getstream-io

The error is intermittent, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't which makes the debugging quite difficult.

- **Machine:** Windows 10
- **Framework:** Laravel 5.1
- **Environment:**

  - **Homestead** 2.2.1
  - **Vagrant**  1.8.1 (**Ubuntu** 14.04.2 LTS GNU/Linux 3.13.0-32-generic x86_64)
  - **PHP** 5.6.10-1+deb.sury.org
- composer.lock

  - **"guzzlehttp/guzzle"**: 6.1.1,
  - **"get-stream/stream-laravel":** "dev-master",

```
ConnectException in CurlFactory.php line 186:
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to us-east-api.getstream.io port 443: Connection timed out (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

```
in CurlFactory.php line 186
at CurlFactory::createRejection(object(EasyHandle), array('errno' => '7', 'error' => 'Failed to connect to us-east-api.getstream.io port 443: Connection timed out', 'url' => 'https://us-east-api.getstream.io/api/v1.0/feed/notification/1/?limit=7&api_key=XXX', 'content_type' => null, 'http_code' => '0', 'header_size' => '0', 'request_size' => '0', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' => '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '4.077293', 'namelookup_time' => '0.127791', 'connect_time' => '0', 'pretransfer_time' => '0', 'size_upload' => '0', 'size_download' => '0', 'speed_download' => '0', 'speed_upload' => '0', 'download_content_length' => '-1', 'upload_content_length' => '-1', 'starttransfer_time' => '0', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => '0', 'local_ip' => '', 'local_port' => '0')) in CurlFactory.php line 150
at CurlFactory::finishError(object(CurlHandler), object(EasyHandle), object(CurlFactory)) in CurlFactory.php line 103
at CurlFactory::finish(object(CurlHandler), object(EasyHandle), object(CurlFactory)) in CurlHandler.php line 43
at CurlHandler->__invoke(object(Request), array('synchronous' => true, 'base_uri' => object(Uri), 'timeout' => '6', 'handler' => object(HandlerStack), 'allow_redirects' => array('max' => '5', 'protocols' => array('http', 'https'), 'strict' => false, 'referer' => false, 'track_redirects' => false), 'http_errors' => true, 'decode_content' => true, 'verify' => true, 'cookies' => false)) in Proxy.php line 28
at Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(object(Request), array('synchronous' => true, 'base_uri' => object(Uri), 'timeout' => '6', 'handler' => object(HandlerStack), 'allow_redirects' => array('max' => '5', 'protocols' => array('http', 'https'), 'strict' => false, 'referer' => false, 'track_redirects' => false), 'http_errors' => true, 'decode_content' => true, 'verify' => true, 'cookies' => false)) in Proxy.php line 51
at Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(object(Request), array('synchronous' => true, 'base_uri' => object(Uri), 'timeout' => '6', 'handler' => object(HandlerStack), 'allow_redirects' => array('max' => '5', 'protocols' => array('http', 'https'), 'strict' => false, 'referer' => false, 'track_redirects' => false), 'http_errors' => true, 'decode_content' => true, 'verify' => true, 'cookies' => false)) in PrepareBodyMiddleware.php line 42
at PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(object(Request), array('synchronous' => true, 'base_uri' => object(Uri), 'timeout' => '6', 'handler' => object(HandlerStack), 'allow_redirects' => array('max' => '5', 'protocols' => array('http', 'https'), 'strict' => false, 'referer' => false, 'track_redirects' => false), 'http_errors' => true, 'decode_content' => true, 'verify' => true, 'cookies' => false)) in Middleware.php line 30
at Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(object(Request), array('synchronous' => true, 'base_uri' => object(Uri), 'timeout' => '6', 'handler' => object(HandlerStack), 'allow_redirects' => array('max' => '5', 'protocols' => array('http', 'https'), 'strict' => false, 'referer' => false, 'track_redirects' => false), 'http_errors' => true, 'decode_content' => true, 'verify' => true, 'cookies' => false)) in RedirectMiddleware.php line 68
at RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(object(Request), array('synchronous' => true, 'base_uri' => object(Uri), 'timeout' => '6', 'handler' => object(HandlerStack), 'allow_redirects' => array('max' => '5', 'protocols' => array('http', 'https'), 'strict' => false, 'referer' => false, 'track_redirects' => false), 'http_errors' => true, 'decode_content' => true, 'verify' => true, 'cookies' => false)) in Middleware.php line 59
at Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(object(Request), array('synchronous' => true, 'base_uri' => object(Uri), 'timeout' => '6', 'handler' => object(HandlerStack), 'allow_redirects' => array('max' => '5', 'protocols' => array('http', 'https'), 'strict' => false, 'referer' => false, 'track_redirects' => false), 'http_errors' => true, 'decode_content' => true, 'verify' => true, 'cookies' => false)) in HandlerStack.php line 67
at HandlerStack->__invoke(object(Request), array('synchronous' => true, 'base_uri' => object(Uri), 'timeout' => '6', 'handler' => object(HandlerStack), 'allow_redirects' => array('max' => '5', 'protocols' => array('http', 'https'), 'strict' => false, 'referer' => false, 'track_redirects' => false), 'http_errors' => true, 'decode_content' => true, 'verify' => true, 'cookies' => false)) in Client.php line 268
at Client->transfer(object(Request), array('synchronous' => true, 'base_uri' => object(Uri), 'timeout' => '6', 'handler' => object(HandlerStack), 'allow_redirects' => array('max' => '5', 'protocols' => array('http', 'https'), 'strict' => false, 'referer' => false, 'track_redirects' => false), 'http_errors' => true, 'decode_content' => true, 'verify' => true, 'cookies' => false, '_conditional' => array('User-Agent' => 'GuzzleHttp/6.1.1 curl/7.35.0 PHP/5.6.10-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1'))) in Client.php line 98
```

Answer (score 1):

As one of the co-founders of Stream I can tell you things are running smoothly on our end :) You can verify the same from Stream's [status page](http://status.getstream.io/) as well.

The timeout errors that you are experiencing can depend on lot of thing. These two are the most common causes for similar issues:

- Slow/inconsistent connection latency between your local dev and our API endpoint
- DNS issues (eg. wrong handling of DNS TTL, bad DNS servers, ...)

My suggestion is to make sure both are taken care of by doing the following:

- Increase the API timeout for your development environment, in the stream-laravel config file make sure you have `'timeout' => 10`.
- Make sure you use something like Google DNS (they work great) the IPs are `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` Since Homestead uses Ubuntu you can refer to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346838/how-do-i-configure-my-dns-settings-in-ubuntu-server)

Comment: Thanks Tommaso! We assume it's something to do with the local environment / vagrant since it doesn't seem to occur on our staging server it's just quite strange that it's on and off. We also tagged homestead / laravel to this question to see if it's a common curl problem in this environment and will try your suggestions. Thanks.